# Is it possible automate switch to window *Completions*?

Tags: selected-window, consult

Linux Mint 20

Emacs 27.1

Install package: Consult, Vertico, Embark

Steps:

```
M-x shell
```

[image]

Input

```
cat test.
```

and press **TAB**

[image]
Open window `*Completions*` with possible candidates. Nice... but the cursor is not focus on this buffer. Cursor is still stay on shell buffer. So as result I need to press `M-<arrow down>` `(windmove-down)` to switch to window `*Completions*` and select desire candidate.
[image]

It's not very convenient. Is it possible when press `TAB` to **automate** switch to window `*Completions*` ?

Comment: What I do is to use the completions window to figure out how much to type before pressing TAB again to restrict the choices further. E.g. here if you want the first file, type `a TAB RET`. I find that much faster than switching windows (although I do that too occasionally when I decide it would take too much typing - but I certainly don't want it done automatically).

Comment: @NickD This help: (setq completion-in-region-function
      (lambda (&rest args)
        (apply (if vertico-mode
                   #'consult-completion-in-region
                   #'completion--in-region)
               args)))

Comment: Can you explain? What does this help? Is it an answer to your question? (if so, you should make it a proper answer).

Comment: @NickD I added my anser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here solution:
In my init.el

```
(require 'consult)

;; Auto switch to buffer *Completition* when press TAB.
;; Use `consult-completion-in-region' if Vertico is enabled.
;; Otherwise use the default `completion--in-region' function.
(setq completion-in-region-function
      (lambda (&rest args)
        (apply (if vertico-mode
                   #'consult-completion-in-region
                   #'completion--in-region)
               args)))
```

Here help:
[consult-completion-in-region](https://github.com/minad/consult#miscellaneous)

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept this answer so the question will be removed from the "unanswered" queue